# Swift macOS how to disable menubar button

Tags: swift

I'm trying to disable the undo and redo buttons in my macOS app. I selected each button and unchecked "enabled" in the attributes inspector, and yet the buttons are still enabled. I discovered that when I remove the IBActions I have associated with each button, *then* they become disabled. But I need the IBActions. Ultimately, I need to programmatically determine whether the buttons are enabled. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to conform your controller, having those actions to `NSUserInterfaceValidations` and provide implementation for

```
func validateUserInterfaceItem(_ item: NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem) -> Bool {
   if item.action == #selector(your_action_here) {
      return // your condition condition for enable/disable
   }
   return false
}
```

Alternate is `NSMenuItemValidation`, but above is more generic.

Related documentations: [User Interface Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/UIValidation.html?language=objc#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000040i)